# Writing G.711 Stream to AVI File

Tags: audio-streaming, pcm, avi

I've inherited an application that opens a proprietary file which has a video stream and an audio stream (G.711 ULAW format). The application already writes the video to an AVI but without the audio.
I want to add code that inserts the audio stream in the same format to the AVI file.

Are there any code samples/documentation that show how to write a G.711 stream into AVI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an update on the solution:

Basically I was doing the right thing and passing the correct codec code (WAVE_FORMAT_MULAW) as Richard suggested.

However, each API call: AVIFileCreateStream and AVIStreamSetFormat accepts a different structure. But not all the fields are relevant for the call, so the rest of the structure has to be filled with zeros before setting each field.

For example:

```
AVISTREAMINFO aviHeader;
ZeroMemory(&aviHeader, sizeof(aviHeader));
aviHeader.fccType = streamtypeAUDIO;
```

...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [AVIFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd756808%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) services can be used to write streams into AVI format.

G.711 u-law is a standard "wave" audio format in Windows.  When you set the format of the audio stream using [AVIStreamSetFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd756856%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), use the [WAVEFORMATEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757712%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure, with `wFormatTag` set to `WAVE_FORMAT_MULAW` (0x0007).

[Update] There is a decent-looking walkthrough of how to read and write AVI files on CodeProject: [Steganography IV - Reading and Writing AVI files](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5294/Steganography-IV-Reading-and-Writing-AVI-files)

Comment: Thank you very much for the support! I will look into that and update here shortly.